# How to use a custom post type as child of a particular post of another CPT?

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting

I have a custom post type `services` which uses a standard page instead of the usual archive (`'has_archive' => false`), so the content is user-editable. This has a url like `/services/`.

One of the posts in `services` is titled "Training". I have a second CPT `courses` which I'd like to be a child of the "Training" post. This should have a url like `/services/training/course-name-here`.

The `courses` post type is registered with the following:

```
'rewrite' => array ('slug' => 'service/training'),
'capability_type' => 'page',
'has_archive' => false,
```

However, a 404 error is returned for the `courses`. Changing the rewrite rule to anything other than `services/training` (eg `abc/training`) and flushing the rewrite rules works, so I guess there's some conflict with the `services` page. How can I resolve this?

Comment: did you make the cpt hierarchical?

Comment: Yes, tried all combinations of both post types setting `'hierarchical' => true`. Further investigation makes me indicates that WordPress thinks the url is an attachment (which doesn't exist, hence the 404).